# how to push to develop branch not master?

Tags: git, github, repository

Whenever I trying pushing with the following command the pull request
that will be created will always be targeted at master branch

`git push origin my_sample_branch`

I already tried setting my upstream with

`git push --set-upstream origin develop`

but I still push to master branch. how come?

Comment: Try `git push origin yourlocalbranch:develop`

Answer (score 3):

Try it with this *command-syntax*:

```
git push <remote> <local_branch>:<remote_branch_name>
```

In your example like:

```
git push origin my_sample_branch:develop
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command:
1.switch branch first
`git switch my_sample_branch`
2.set the upstream branch
`git branch -u origin/develop`
3. push directly, it will push to the upstream branch automatically
`git push`

By the way, you can check the upstream branch by command `git branch -vv`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
git push origin your_local_branch : your_remote_branch
```

Worked for me